# Parsing XML with embedded node in text to DataFrame

Tags: pandas, xml, parsing

I have an XML like this:

```xml
<root>
    <epig>
    string1
    <tit>string2</tit>
    string3
    </epig>
</root>
```

I'm trying to build a data frame with following:

```py
dftext = pd.read_xml("filename.xml", xpath='root/epig')
```

which returns in the data frame a column `epig` containing string1 and a column `tit` with `string2`, but `string3` is disappeared in data frame. This is the current output:

| epig | tit |
| --- | --- |
| string1 | string2 |

The data frame output instead should be:

| epig | tit |
| --- | --- |
| string1+string3 | string 2 |

Where's my error?

Comment: Can you edit your question and show your exact expected output?

Comment: I think the error would be in your XML, no? If you moved 'string3' above 'string2' then 'string'3 would probably come through in the epig column. I think you'd probably need extra keys (eg epig1 and epig2 for the separate values) but im not sure how pandas deals with nested xml

Comment: Yes, it's a bad xml, but it's not mine, I received a lot of files written in this manner

Answer (score 1):

In XML speak, there are three nodes under the `<epig>` element: two `<text>` nodes and the `<tit>` node. To retrieve the latter text node, in Python's `etree` library, you would have to use the [**`.tail`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail) attribute on the `tit` element. In Pandas, `read_xml` (the convenience method designed to parse flat not all XML types) only parses the first text node since it does not iterate across multiple text nodes.

For this special use case of multiple text nodes, consider re-styling the XML with [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files, which is supported in [**`read_xml`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) using the `stylesheet` argument and default `lxml` parser (not `etree` parser).

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl, a special .xml file)*

Below concatenates both text nodes into a new `<epig>` child element that becomes a sibling to `<tit>` each under a new parent `<item>` used in `xpath`.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="epig"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="epig">
     <item>
       <epig>
         <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(concat(text()[1], text()[2]))"/>
       </epig>
       <xsl:copy-of select="tit"/>
     </item>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4FpKw/1)</kbd>

**Python**

Below will parse all `<item>` nodes of the flattened output of XSLT.

```py
dftext = pd.read_xml("filename.xml", xpath=".//item", stylesheet="style.xsl")

dftext
#               epig      tit
# 0  string1 string3  string2
```